# Jade sets it's own style tag to every p element

Tags: pug

In my website, I wondered why I couldn't set a font size for my p elements, and it turns out jade has been adding style="font-size: 12px" to all my p elements as if I did it. Any way to fix this? It's probably my fault but I don't know what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really stupid, sorry about that, it was my own js file adding it on.